Probably of choosing the same number of balls of each colour from a pot with $n_1$ of one colour and $n_2$ of another
I recently answered this question, where $2k$ balls are drawn, one at a time and with replacement, from a pot with $n/2$ black balls and $n/2$ white balls (I've rescaled the total number of balls from the original question).
Because it is with replacement, there are always the same number of each ball when drawing, so there's a 50/50 chance each time of drawing a specific colour. I used this fact to show that the probability of drawing the same number of each colour is independent of $n$.
Instead, what if there were $n_1$ black balls and $n_2$ white (with $n=n_1+n_2$ and in general $n_1\neq n_2$) so that in each draw $P(\text{black})=n_1/n$ and $P(\text{white})=n_2/n$. What now is the probability of drawing the same number of balls?
Because combinations with different numbers of each ball are no longer equiprobable, I'm not sure how to calculate a total probability, as you can't use favourable cases divided by total cases.

This is a binomial distribution.  See Binomial Distribution,
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$
Think of success as drawing a white ball.  You are asking for the probability that in exactly $~2k~$ trials, there will be exactly $~k~$ successes.
Since the sampling is by replacement, the probability of success in each trial is
$$p = \frac{n_2}{n},$$
and the probability of failure in each trial is
$$q = 1 - p = \frac{n_1}{n}.$$
Therefore, the desired computation is
$$\binom{2k}{k} p^k q^k.$$

Neat, thanks! And when $p=q=1/2$, $p^kq^k$ reduces to the $1/2^{2k}$ from the original question.
